# How I can deselect button in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, query-string

I have some buttons like a category. When I click on one of them I get the card with some information.

```html
<app-category-button [label]='category.name'
      [isSelected]='category.id === (selectedCategoryId$ | async)'
      [routerLink]='["."]' [queryParams]='{categoryId: category.id, page: 1}'
          queryParamsHandling='merge'>
</app-category-button>
```

app-category-button selector:

```html
<button mat-stroked-button
        class='category-item font-medium'
        [ngClass]='{"bg-primary-500 text-white": isSelected,
        "text-primary-500  bg-lightbluebg-500": !isSelected}'>
   {{label}}
</button>
```

When I click on the button I get in my route the queryParams that open my cards with information.

The question is how on the second click to that button hide queryParams and deselect the button?

[image: not clicked button]

[image: clicked button]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
        this.queryParams = params.hasOwnProperty('categoryId') ? 
            {} : {categoryId: category.id, page: 1}
    }
);
```

And use queryParams in your template as

```
<app-category-button [label]='category.name'
    [isSelected]='category.id === (selectedCategoryId$ | async)'
      [routerLink]='["."]' [queryParams]='queryParams'
          queryParamsHandling='merge'>
</app-category-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the category only on the button for the selected one, you can change the `categoryId` query param to null only on click on that button.

```html
<app-category-button [label]='category.name'
      [isSelected]='category.id === (selectedCategoryId$ | async)'
      [routerLink]='["."]' [queryParams]='{categoryId: (selectedCategoryId$ | async) ? null : category.id, page: 1}'
          queryParamsHandling='merge'>
</app-category-button>
```

For the rest categories, it would still change load the respective category.

Answer (score 0):

#### Accessing the router state

To retrieve the current variables from a route or current query params, use the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)-service.

In your routing, e.g. `AppRouting`:

```js
import RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'test/:id', component: MyComponent }
])
```

in your component:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // snapshot gets the params just once
    this.doSomethingWithRouteParams( 
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params,
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);

    // you can also listen to the changes using RxJS observables
    combineLatest([
      this.activatedRoute.paramMap,
      this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap 
    ])  
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
       .subscribe(([params, queryParams]) => 
          this.doSomethingWithRouteParams(params, queryParams));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  private doSomethingWithRouteParams(params: ParamMap, queryParams: ParamMap): void {
    console.log({ 
      id: params.get('id'), // use the same param-name as in the router-config
      categoryId: queryParams.get('categoryId'),
      page: queryParams.get('page'),
    });
  }
}
```

See https://angular.io/guide/router-reference#activated-route for a list of properties on the activated route.

#### Conditional class binding

I assume by "deselecting the button" you probably mean conditionally binding the CSS classes. There are several ways to achieve this in Angular, the one I prefer over others due to readability would look like so:

```html
<button 
  mat-stroked-button
  class="category-item font-medium"
  [class.text-white]="isSelected"
  [class.bg-primary-500]="isSelected"
  [class.text-primary-500]="!isSelected"
  [class.bg-lightbluebg-500]="!isSelected"
>
   {{ label }}
</button>
```

See the guide on [binding to attributes](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding) and [to the class attribute](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-class-attribute) in particular.

#### Hint regarding the `async` pipe

Also, just as a side note: Note that `[isSelected]='category.id === (selectedCategoryId$ | async)'` will create a new subscription for every single `app-category-button` instance in this template. This might cause poor performance so you probably should refactor this to get the selected category just once, e.g.:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf=(selectedCategoryId$ | async) as selectedCategoryId>

  <app-category-button 
    label="Category #1" 
    [isSelected]="1 === selectedCategoryId"
  ></app-category-button>

  <app-category-button 
    label="Category #2" 
    [isSelected]="2 === selectedCategoryId"
  ></app-category-button>

  <app-category-button 
    label="Category #3" 
    [isSelected]="3 === selectedCategoryId"
  ></app-category-button>

</ng-container>
```

Please refer to the "*Consuming observable data with ngIf and the async pipe*"-section in the [Angular ngIf: Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngif/)

Comment: By clicking on selected category I want to hide opened cards and deselect button

Comment: Showing an element conditionally is done with `ngIf`:  `<app-my-card *ngIf="isSelected">...</app-my-card>`

Comment: Is your question about how to retrieve the current query params to update your `isSelected` state?

Comment: Additionally, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-query-parameters